# C++ Vector Returned from function not printing right values

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, vector

I have `class A` and a `main()` function:

```
class A {
    public: int num;
    public: A* parent;

    A(){};

    A::A (const A &s)
    {
        this->num = s.num;
        this->parent = s.parent;
    }

    public : vector <A> foo(A a)
    {
        A a1;
        a1.num = a.num;
        a1.parent = &a;
    
        vector <A> list;
        list.reserve(1);
        list.push_back(a1);
        
        A temp = list.front();
    
        cout << temp.parent->num << endl;

        return list;
    }
}; 

int main()
{
    A a; 
    a.num =2;

    vector <A> list = a.foo(a);

    A temp = list.front();

    cout << temp.parent->num << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that `cout` inside `foo()` prints 2 as expected, but `cout` inside `main()` is printing a huge number.

I assume the problem is something related to memory rellocation, as I read from multiple sources, so I tried using `reserve()` but it didn't work.

Can anyone help me solve this problem?

Comment: vector <A> foo(A a)
        {
        A a1;
        a1.num = a.num;
        a1.parent = &a; <-- problem here : what is the lifetime of a ?

Comment: @jsl28 what do you mean by lifetime ?

Comment: How long is the object valid? At what point does it go out of scope and is no more? Think on the usefulness of having a pointer to an object that has passed out of scope and been destroyed.

Comment: @geon_is_here `a1.parent = &a;` -- That `a` variable goes up in a puff of smoke when the `foo` function returns.  So what will you be pointing to once that happens? -- *I assume the problem is something related to memory rellocation as I read from multiple sources* -- The most elementary C++ book should have explained variable lifetimes.

Comment: @paulMckenzie and how do think the problem should be solved  I am kind of restricted in the code to have a function the returns vector in main function

Comment: No matter what problem you're solving, you cannot store addresses of local variables that will go out-of-scope and expect anything other than undefined behavior from occurring.

Comment: your problem is not with vector, but with your class A. get rid of the pointers.

Comment: @NeilButterworth I can't get rid of the pointers , I need to access the parent pointer in some parts of my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `foo()`, you are passing in the `a` parameter *by value*. That means the `A` object that `main()` is passing to `foo()` gets *copied* into the `a` parameter.  The `a` parameter itself is a local variable to `foo()`.  As such, `a1.parent` is being set to point at a local variable.

And then `list.push_back(a1);` makes a *copy* of `a1`, which copies the `parent` pointer.  And then you are making another *copy* when saving the result of `list.front()` to `temp`.

Consequently, dereferencing the `temp.parent` pointer inside of `foo()` is perfectly valid, since `a` that `parent` is pointing at is still valid in memory.

However, once `foo()` exits, `a` gets destroyed, leaving the copied `parent` pointer(s) dangling, pointing at now-invalid memory.  As such, in `main()`, dereferencing the `parent` pointer is *undefined behavior* since that pointer is no longer pointing at the original `a` object.

You can easily see this for yourself if you add some logging for the construction and destruction of your `A` objects, eg:

```cpp
class A {
public:
    int num = 0;
    A* parent = nullptr;
 
    A(){ cout << "A created: " << this << endl; }
 
    A(const A &s) : num(s.num), parent(s.parent)
    {
        cout << "A copied: " << &s << " -> " << this << endl;
    }
 
    ~A(){ cout << "A destroyed: " << this << endl; }

    ...
};
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/GTKClx)

You will see something like this being logged:

```
A created: 0x7ffe5e735250                   // 'a' in main() is created
A copied: 0x7ffe5e735250 -> 0x7ffe5e735260  // 'a' in foo() is passed in by main()
A created: 0x7ffe5e7351e0                   // 'a1' in foo() is created
A copied: 0x7ffe5e7351e0 -> 0x5592f50b2e80  // 'a1' is copied into `list` in foo()
A copied: 0x5592f50b2e80 -> 0x7ffe5e7351f0  // list.front() is copied into 'temp' in foo()
(foo) temp.parent: 0x7ffe5e735260, num: 2   // parent is pointing at 'a' in foo()
                                            // foo() exits, 'list' is transferred to main()
A destroyed: 0x7ffe5e7351f0                 // 'temp' in foo() is destroyed
A destroyed: 0x7ffe5e7351e0                 // 'a1' in foo() is destroyed
A destroyed: 0x7ffe5e735260                 // 'a' in foo() is destroyed !!!!!
A copied: 0x5592f50b2e80 -> 0x7ffe5e735260  // main() reuses freed memory for 'temp' in main() !!!!!
(main) temp.parent: 0x7ffe5e735260, num: 2  // parent is pointing at the wrong A object !!!!!
                                            // main exits
A destroyed: 0x7ffe5e735260                 // 'temp' in main() is destroyed
A destroyed: 0x5592f50b2e80                 // `list` in main() is destroyed
A destroyed: 0x7ffe5e735250                 // 'a' in main() is destroyed
```

To solve this issue, change `foo()` to take in the `A` object *by reference* instead (and also change the two `temp` variables to be `A&` references, as well):

```cpp
vector<A> foo(A &a)
```

This way, in `main()`, the returned `parent` pointer will remain valid as long as the local `a` object that is being passed into `foo()` remains valid.

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/6kSXs6)

Now, you will see something like this being logged instead:

```
A created: 0x7ffd7319e8b0                   // 'a' in main() is created
                                            // 'a' in foo() is passed in by main()
A created: 0x7ffd7319e850                   // 'a1' in `foo() is created
A copied: 0x7ffd7319e850 -> 0x556ccff0fe80  // 'a1' is copied into 'list' in foo()
(foo) temp.parent: 0x7ffd7319e8b0, num: 2   // parent is pointing at 'a' in main()
                                            // foo() exits, 'list' is transferred to main()
A destroyed: 0x7ffd7319e850                 // 'a1' in foo() is destroyed
(main) temp.parent: 0x7ffd7319e8b0, num: 2  // parent is still pointing at 'a' in main()
                                            // main() exits
A destroyed: 0x556ccff0fe80                 // 'list' in main() is destroyed. 
A destroyed: 0x7ffd7319e8b0                 // 'a' in main() is destroyed !!!!!
```